# Does the post method all the function to display in Flask

Tags: python, flask, facebook-messenger, http-method

I am writing these two following function in my code to be able to process incoming messages and respond back to the user on Messenger via a bot:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['post'])
def webhook():
    # endpoint for processing incoming messaging events
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)  # you may not want to log every incoming message in production, but it's good for testing
    if data["object"] == "page":
        for entry in data["entry"]:
            for messaging_event in entry["messaging"]:
                if messaging_event.get("message"):  # someone sent us a message
                    sender_id = messaging_event["sender"]["id"]        # the Facebook ID of the person sending you the message
                    recipient_id = messaging_event["recipient"]["id"]  # the recipient's ID, which should be your page's facebook ID
                    message_text = messaging_event["message"]["text"]  # the message's text
                    responseai = response(message_text, sender_id)
                    send_message(sender_id, responseai)
                if messaging_event.get("delivery"):  # delivery confirmation
                    pass
                if messaging_event.get("optin"):  # optin confirmation
                    pass
                if messaging_event.get("postback"):  # user clicked/tapped "postback" button in earlier message
                    pass
    return "Ok", 200





 @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
 def verify():
    # when the endpoint is registered as a web hook, it must echo back
    # the 'hub.challenge' value it receives in the query arguments
    if request.args.get("hub.mode") == "subscribe" and request.args.get("hub.challenge"):
        if not request.args.get("hub.verify_token") == os.environs["VERIFY_TOKEN"]:
            return "Verification token mismatch", 403
        return request.args["hub.challenge"], 200

    return "Hello World", 200
```

When I access my localhost:5000 where my Flask is, only Hello World appears on the browser. How would I know that the function web-hook is working? Should it also display the 'Ok'?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will not send a POST request, not without some additional HTML and Javascript coding. The simplest way to test if your hook works is by using the [`curl` command-line client](https://curl.haxx.se/).

It can send both GET and POST requests. Testing if your `GET` handler works correctly:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:5000/?hub.verify_token=<YOUR_VERIFY_TOKEN>&hub.challenge=CHALLENGE_ACCEPTED&hub.mode=subscribe"
```

should produce `CHALLENGE_ACCEPTED` as the output. Then test the `POST` handler with:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST "localhost:5000/" -d '{"sender":{"id":"<PSID>"}, "recipient":{"id":"<PAGE_ID>"}, "timestamp":1458692752478, "message":{"mid":"mid.1457764197618:41d102a3e1ae206a38", "text":"hello, world!", "quick_reply": {"payload": "<DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD>"}}}'
```

See the [*Setting Up Your Webhook* section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup) of the Messenger Platform Getting Started documentation, and the [*message received* event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messages) for details on what to expect when handling a message event.

Another option is to [write Python tests](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/) to cover the same:

```
import os
import pytest

import your_flask_module

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    your_flask_module.app.config['TESTING'] = True
    yield your_flask_module.app.test_client()

def test_register(client):
    args = {
        'hub.verify_token': os.environ["VERIFY_TOKEN"],
        'hub.challenge': 'CHALLENGE_ACCEPTED',
        'hub.mode': 'subscribe',
    }
    rv = client.get('/', params=args)
    assert b'CHALLANGE_ACCEPTED' in rv.data

def test_message_event(client):
    event = {
        "sender": {"id": "<PSID>"},
        "recipient": {"id":"<PAGE_ID>"},
        "timestamp": 1458692752478,
        "message": {
            "mid": "mid.1457764197618:41d102a3e1ae206a38",
            "text": "hello, world!",
            "quick_reply": {
                "payload": "<DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD>"
            }
        }
    }
    rv = client.post('/', json=event)
    assert rv.status_code == 200
```

Comment: I already run the CURL command in node js to set up my webhook but when I check my localhost I still only have Hello world displayed. Actually I already set up everything for my messenger bot but it was not reply due to an error and I thought that it was due to the POST.

Comment: @HateefaLowKom: but are you making a `POST` request with curl?

Comment: no I am not. Actually I already set up everything for my messenger bot but it was not reply due to an error and I thought that it was due to the POST since I got a server error and when I checker my Heroku logs I had this '2019-03-12T17:46:43.138555+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=chatbottestbot.herokuapp.com request_id=785623ad-1d13-4d72-a42a-1c3f24595035 fwd="31.13.115.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=500 bytes=456 protocol=https'

Comment: @HateefaLowKom: without logging, it is impossible to tell what caused the 500 error. I strongly suggest you write tests *at the very least*.